# (DiscordJS) Trying to fetch messages before message ID but keep getting the most recent one

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a range of messages I want to fetch to be deleted. If I pass 3-5 for example and I have 5 messages * a b c d e*

I expect my command `^delmsg 3-5` to delete *d* and  *c*.

I managed to get the ID (a snowflake) of *d* and tried to pass it to `before`, but it keeps fetching my command and *e* instead of *d* and *c*. I don't know what else I can do with this. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with promises that I'm not aware of.

Code:

```
const deleter = (message, range) => {
    const range1 = range[0]; //indexes are already an array so we get the first index 
    const amnt = parseInt(range[1]) - parseInt(range[0]); //makes the str index ints
    var msgs, nID;
    
    message.channel.messages.fetch({
        limit: range1,
    }).then(a => {
        msgs = Array.from(a);
        nID = msgs[range1-1][0];
    }).then(message.channel.messages.fetch({
        limit: amnt,
        before: nID,
    }).then(b => {
        //message.channel.bulkDelete(b);
    }));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then` expects an uncalled function. You should use an arrow function there too, and it should work as intended

```js
 message.channel.messages.fetch({
        limit: range1,
    }).then(a => {
        msgs = Array.from(a);
        nID = msgs[range1-1][0];
    }).then(() => message.channel.messages.fetch({ //notice it's an arrow function
        limit: amnt,
        before: nID,
    })).then(b => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(b);
    })
```

Also you should note the extra bracket at the end should go after the `.then` where you fetch the messages.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked.

Comment: I have a quick question if you don't mind. Is this the best way to go about doing what I'm doing? It looks very ugly, but it's the shortest way I could come up with.

Comment: Using `async-await`. Make sure at the top of the callback before the params/function name you write `async`. Then, for each `fetch` you will await it

Comment: Example: `const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch({
        limit: range1,
    });
msgs = Array.from(messages);
nID = msgs[range1-1][0];
const filtered = await message.channel.messages.fetch({
        limit: amnt,
        before: nID,
    });
message.channel.bulkDelete(filtered);
`

Comment: The above is not formatted because comments can't have linebreaks, you will have to separate them yourself. I added semi-colons to make it easier